# Equivalent of a nested model in Oracle Apex or how to make a nested report

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

I have a problem with generating a report in Oracle Apex. I want to show a report for an entity and its children.
There are customers. Customers have 0 or many IT-architectures. IT-architectures consist of 0 or many IT-systems and 0 or many IT-service-providers.

Right now I select this data with a join (IT-service-providers aren't implemented yet, so We have only cutomers, it-architectures and it-systems):
(KUNDEN = Customers)

```
SELECT ISP_KUNDEN.*,
  ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN.ARCHITEKTUR_ID,
  ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN.VERSION,
  ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN.THEMA,
  ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN.STATUS,
  ...
  ISP_IT_SYSTEME.SYSTEM_ID,
  ISP_IT_SYSTEME.NAME,
  ISP_IT_SYSTEME.PRODUKTFAMILIE,
  ...

FROM ISP_KUNDEN
LEFT JOIN ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN
ON ISP_KUNDEN.KIS_NUMMER = ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN.KUNDEN_KIS_NUMMER

LEFT JOIN ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN_IT_SYSTEME
ON ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN.ARCHITEKTUR_ID = ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN_IT_SYSTEME.ARCHITEKTUR_ID

LEFT JOIN ISP_IT_SYSTEME
ON ISP_ARCHITEKTUREN_IT_SYSTEME.IT_SYSTEM_ID = ISP_IT_SYSTEME.SYSTEM_ID
```

The Output is this:
[image: Default interactive report]

This doesn't look good, since all information about the customer and the architecture are listed multiple times if a customer has more then one architecture or an architecture has more then one it-system. Using control breaks, it looks a bit better.

But still, the it-architectures are listed multiple times for each it-system.
Is there a way to make it look like in the example below, without hard-coding html tables?

[image: Example for an ideal output]

I want to be able to search within this nested reports, so hardcoding html tables is not an option. The goal is to be able to filter the customers by the it-systems. Example: Show me users that use System A and System B. With the join I use now, this doesn't work. Do I need to use a group by within the query?

I would like to be able to post images, but stackoverflow is a bit restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

This example comes from the standard apex demo application that get created when you request  a workspace on apex.oracle.com

```
select  
  lpad(to_char(o.order_id),4,'0000') order_number,
  o.order_id,  
  to_date(to_char(o.order_timestamp,'mm yyyy'), 'mm yyyy') order_month,   
  trunc(o.order_timestamp) order_date,
   o.user_name sales_rep, 
  o.order_total,  
  c.cust_last_name || ', ' || c.cust_first_name customer_name,
  (select count(*) from demo_order_items  oi where oi.order_id = o.order_id) order_items,
  o.tags tags
from  
  demo_orders o,  
  demo_customers c
where  
  o.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

## Original List

[image: Original List]

### After adding control break Actions>Format>Control Break

[image: After adding control break Actions>Format>Control Break]

Comment: Hey Jan,thanks for the reply. I know about control breaks. But it's not the right thing. They help to group all IT-architekctures of a customer, but not the it-sysems. I would need something like a nested control break within the it-architecture row (as you can see in the example table).